# how to find major axis and minor axis of each object in an labeled image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am currently using the `bwconncomp` function like so:

```
CC = bwconncomp(BW);
```

`BW` is an input binary image. `CC` is a structure with four fields. `bwconncomp` labels each object in an image.now i want to find major axis and minor axis of each object i have tried using `regionprops` but not getting results.

here is my code

```
inimage = imread('Capture.PNG');
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(inimage);
title('original image');
BW=im2bw(inimage);
subplot(2,3,3);
imshow(BW);
title('binary image');
```

The relevant code:

```
CC = bwconncomp(BW);
stats = regionprops('table',BW,'Centroid','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength')
```

Comment: Why don't you show that code you tried that would be much useful to get a better answer

Comment: In what way are you "not getting results". Making us guess is not very productive.

Comment: @beaker i am getting error not getting any output.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, I was going to have a really hard time responding to this without being terribly sarcastic ;)

Comment: @beaker lol. To be honest, I held back. I hate it when people assume we are clairvoyant. I have an error.... OK... So what mystical error is this?! Lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
LB = bwlabel( BW ); %// label the components in the image
stats = regionprops(LB,'Centroid','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
```

Comment: Ah, so you think the OP has an older version of Matlab that doesn't support tables? Even so, `regionprops` should still take BW images as input, right?

Comment: @beaker - Depending on what version of MATLAB / image processing toolbox you have, recent versions of MATLAB can accept grayscale images for `regionprops`.  I can't remember which version it started to take in grayscale, but it was fairly recent.

Comment: @rayryeng I didn't remember that, but that would make sense. Sounds like `doc regionprops` is in order for the OP to see what their specific version supports.

Comment: @beaker - Ah, I was misinformed.  It's not a grayscale image, but you can specify a **label matrix**... so something like the output of `bwlabel` for example.  I was confused, but it can accept in more than just a binary image.  Oops!